# Is it possible to prove $\arg\min_a f(\max(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}_i)) = \arg\min_a f(\mathbf{a}^T\max(\mathbf{b}_i))$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, optimization, special-functions

I have the following optimization problem,

$ \arg\min_\mathbf{a} f(\max(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}_i))\;\; i=1, \dots ,N$

where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ are vectors of dimension $d$. 
Let $B = \left[\mathbf{b}_1, \dots, \mathbf{b}_N\right]$.

Can I write the above optimization problem as

$\arg\min f(\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{c})$

where $\mathbf{c}$ contains the elements which are the rowwise maximum of $B$.

e.g. $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 \\
5 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \implies \mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
4
\end{bmatrix}$

If $d = 1$, and $a$ is positive, assume $\mathbf{b} = [2,-1, 4, 5]$

$\arg\min f(\max(a\left[2,-1, 4, 5\right])) = \arg\min f(a \max \left[2,-1, 4, 5\right])$

But I dont know how can I prove this for vectors ($d>1$) under some assumptions (e.g. all the elements in $\mathbf{a}$ or $B$ are positive?

Comment: You should provide information about $f$

Comment: What do you mean by $f(\max(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}_i))$? For each $i$, this is a separate and different function of the vector $\mathbf{a}$.